# Am I defining all my keys correctly? Do I need to add an index?

Tags: sqlite, indexing, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I have a couple tables: Accounts and Employees, and I am trying to store a Rating and Timestamp for any given combination between Accounts and Employees. It should not be possible for two ratings to exist for the same timestamp for a given Account + Employee combination.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
    _ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    account_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    employee_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    rating REAL NOT NULL, 
    timestamp LONG NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY(account_id) REFERENCES ACCOUNTS(_ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY(employee_id) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES(_ID), 
    UNIQUE (account_id, employee_id, timestamp));
```

Is this the correct way to define what I am trying to do? Do I also need to create a separate index?

```
CREATE INDEX main_table_idx ON main_table (account_id, employee_id, timestamp);
```

Comment: How is this a java or android question?

Comment: What's wrong with the `UNIQUE` index in your table?

Comment: @shmosel Idk last time I didn't include that I was using Java/Android I got chastised, so I always include it now

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that Java/Android was relevant last time.

Comment: In my opinion it wasn't relevant last time, either, but what can you do -- StackOverflow is impossible to please sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique constraints are implemented using a unique index.

Hence, separately creating the index is not necessary.

As explained in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

> In most cases, UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints are implemented by
>   creating a unique index in the database. (The exceptions are INTEGER
>   PRIMARY KEY and PRIMARY KEYs on WITHOUT ROWID tables.)

Based on your description, the unique constraint seems correct.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question as stated

Comment: @user6183183 . . . "Do I also need to create a separate index?"

Comment: I don't understand what that documentation snippet is saying. What is it saying in plain English?

Comment: @user6183183 . . . It is just saying what the first sentence in the answer says.:  if you create a unique constraint then you don't need an additional index.  It is already there.